# Reading numpad symbols under Mono

Tags: c#, .net, mono, num-lock

I am developing a console application, that should listen for digits from a numpad keyboard in both num lock states - on and off. The application is running on Raspberry Pi with Arch Linux and Mono. Since I did not found a way, that is compiling under Mono, to permanently turn numlock on, I am using the following method to convert num pad commands to digits:

```
private string ReadNumPadSymbol(ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo)
    {
        char editedSymbol;
        switch (keyInfo.Key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.Insert:
                editedSymbol = '0';
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.End:
                editedSymbol = '1';
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                editedSymbol = '2';
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.PageDown:
                editedSymbol = '3';
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                editedSymbol = '4';
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.Clear:
                editedSymbol = '5';
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                editedSymbol = '6';
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.Home:
                editedSymbol = '7';
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                editedSymbol = '8';
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.PageUp:
                editedSymbol = '9';
                break;
            default:
                return String.Empty;
        }
        return editedSymbol.ToString();
    }
```

It works as expected under Windows, but under Linux, the method returns empty string, when the "5" button is pressed. For some reason it does not enters the ConsoleKey.Clear case. Is there a fix for this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can rely on the keypad's `5` key being mapped to `ConsoleKey.Clear` when NumLock is off in the general case. For instance, on my Linux box `xev` says the key gets mapped to `keycode 84 (keysym 0xff9d, KP_Begin)`.

Comment: Why not print the enum value when 5 key is pressed?